# How do I get the same array? php, Laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have a cart. The add function will create the following array:

```
__PHP_Incomplete_Class Object
(
    [__PHP_Incomplete_Class_Name] => App\Classes\Cart
    [items] => Array
        (
            [3] => Array
                (
                    [name] => LG F2T3HS6W
                    [qty] => 1
                    [prod_url] => lg_f2t3hs6w
                    [code_cat] => large-home-appliances
                    [url_cat] => washing-machines
                    [img] => img_10.jpg
                    [cost] => 380
                )

        )

    [totalQty] => 380
    [totalPrice] => 380

)
```

Here's the code:

```
public function add($item, $id){
      $storedItem = [
        'qty' => 0,
        'id' => $item->id,
        'prod_url' => $item->url,
        'code_cat' => $item->category->code,
        'url_cat' => $item->category->url,
        'name' => $item->name,
        'cost' => $item->price,
        'price' => $item->price,
        'img' => $item->cardImage->path
      ];
      if($this->items){
        if(array_key_exists($id, $this->items)){
          $storedItem = $this->items[$id];
        }
      }
        $storedItem['qty']++;
        $storedItem['cost'] = $item->price * $storedItem['qty'];
        $this->items[$id] = $storedItem;
        $this->totalQty++;
        $this->totalPrice += $item->price;
    }
```

I'm interested in what's outside the array: `totalPrice` and `totalQty`.

I have a modal window. With the help of ajax, it also generates an order. There I am trying to make the same array, to avoid errors when displaying orders in the admin panel.

Ajax:

```
$('.modal.fade').find('.submitModal').click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        let id=parseInt($('.card').find('.modal_order').attr('data-id'));
        let qty=parseInt($('input[name=inputModal]').val());
        let username=$('input[name=name]').val();
        let email=$('input[name=email]').val();
        let phone=$('input[name=phone]').val();

        $.ajax( {
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                }

                ,
                url: '/modal/place-order',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'JSON',
                data: {
                    id:id,
                    qty:qty,
                    username:username,
                    email:email,
                    phone:phone
                }

                ,
                success: function(response) {
                    $('#staticBackdrop').modal('hide');
                    $('.notif_text').html(response.notif_text);

                    setTimeout(function () {
                            $('.toast').toast('show');
                        }

                        , 250);
                }
            }

        );
        return false;
    }

);
```

CartController:

```
public function modal_order_place(Request $request){

    $product = Product::find($request->id);
    $selprod['items'] = array(
      $request->id => array(
          'name' => $product->name,
          'qty' => $request->qty,
          'prod_url' => $product->url,
          'code_cat' => $product->category->code,
          'url_cat' => $product->category->url,
          'img' => $product->cardImage->path,
          'cost' => $product->price*$request->qty
        )
      );

    $object = (object)$selprod;
    $order = new Order();

    $order->cart = serialize($object);

    $order->name = $request->username;
    $order->email = $request->email;
    $order->phone = $request->phone;

    Auth::check()?Auth::user()->orders()->save($order):$order->save();

    return response()->json([
      'notif_text' => 'Your order is being processed'
    ]);
  }
```

Here in the controller I am trying to make this array. So I will make it in the same form as the cart. While it looks like this:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [items] => Array
        (
            [3] => Array
                (
                    [name] => LG F2T3HS6W
                    [qty] => 1
                    [prod_url] => lg_f2t3hs6w
                    [code_cat] => large-home-appliances
                    [url_cat] => washing-machines
                    [img] => img_10.jpg
                    [cost] => 380
                )
        )

)
```

When I try to do so:

```
$request->id => array(
          'name' => $product->name,
          'qty' => $request->qty,
          'prod_url' => $product->url,
          'code_cat' => $product->category->code,
          'url_cat' => $product->category->url,
          'img' => $product->cardImage->path,
          'cost' => $product->price*$request->qty
        ),
          'totalQty' => Something,
          'totalPrice' => Something
      );
```

And it turns out like this:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [items] => Array
        (
            [3] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Стиральная машина LG F2T3HS6W
                    [qty] => 1
                    [prod_url] => lg_f2t3hs6w
                    [code_cat] => large-home-appliances
                    [url_cat] => washing-machines
                    [img] => img_10.jpg
                    [cost] => 380
                )

            [totalQty] => Something
            [totalPrice] => Something
        )

)
```

How can I take this data out of the array, but leave it inside the object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are adding `totalQty` and `totalPrice` in the same "level" as your `$request->id'.
You should have your expected result doing this:

```php
$selprod['totalQty'] = Something ;
$selprod['totalPrice'] = Something ;
```